# Automatic Table Snapshot (No jobs) SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to save the information from a table `inventory` to another table `inventoryHistory` at certain hour. (It changes along the day).

I only need to run an `insert into select` query but I don't know how to automatically run it.

- I don't have access to program a job in the database.
- I was thinking in use a trigger (In every change) but I don't know if that's going to affect the performance of the database (Because of the validation in every movement).
- The other option is create an application that executes the query at a certain hour.  (In this case I would like to run it like a service or something that I don't need to have open in my desktop.)

I really don't know which is the best option or if there's another, I would rather use SQL only if its possible.

Comment: Have you already looked into SQL Server Agent?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "I don't have access to program a job in the database." I assume that this means you cannot use SQL Server Agent jobs because of permissions issues, or whoever controls the database or server won't allow it to be installed. In that case, the only way I can see to do this is a perpetual SQL process - one that uses an unending `WHILE` loop, and the `WAITFOR` command to keep from consuming massive resources. See below for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could use that kind of query but I always have trouble with them because as soon as the SPID is killed for whatever reason, it just fails silently and won't restart itself. I'd sooner suggest to skip the headache and ask for permission to run a nightly job.

Comment: They are a headache. However, they are sometimes necessary based on the limitations placed on the coder by whoever controls the systems involved.

Comment: No, I can't use agent jobs. I think I'm going to use the permanent loop.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server Agent / Job / Job Scheduler to automate it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

First, create the archive command as a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ArchiveMyTable
AS
    INSERT INTO MyTableArchive
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable m
    [Conditions and WHERE clauses here]
```

Then, you need to get this command executed once per startup on the server

```
DECLARE @NextTime char(8)
WHILE 1 <> 0
BEGIN
    -- Calculate next run here
    -- This example just runs every hour at 15 minutes after the hour
    SET @NextTime = CONVERT(varchar(3), DateAdd(Hour, 1, Dateadd(minute, -15, Getdate())), 108) + '15:00' -- Returns 'hh:15:00'
    WAITFOR TIME @NextTime
    EXEC ArchiveMyTable
END
```

This will execute the stored procedure at the time specified.

Comment: You can also have something that checks if the process is still running, then executes the command if it is not. This adds complexity, but may be necessary based on your situation.